# Tikz-qtree will not work (error: missing \endcsname inserted)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

MikTex version is 2.9, Texstudio version is 2.12.22.

I can't make the MWE quite as short as I'd like, because my document has a lot of prefatory material and requires many packages. Given that I have no clue whether it's something in the preamble or the `tikzpicture` call itself that causes the problem, I have to include pretty much everything:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
 \usepackage[toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
 \makeglossaries
\usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{tabu}
 \usepackage{float} 
 \usepackage{tipa}
 \usepackage{leipzig}
 \usepackage{caption} 
 \usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxnames = 6]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{sorsat.bib}
 \usepackage{mathptmx} 
 \usepackage{gb4e} 
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
 \noautomath
 \usepackage{soul}
 \usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
 \setacronymstyle{long-short}
 \newglossaryentry{dagger}{name = \ensuremath{\dagger}, description=Abridged corpus example}
 \newacronym{hp}{H\&P}{Huddleston and Pullum (2002)}
 \newacronym{NOW}{NOW}{Corpus of News on the Web}
 \newacronym{bnc}{BNC}{The British National Corpus} 

 \begin{document}
    \author{My Anonymized Name}
    \title{My Anonymized Title}
    \date{October 2020}

    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \printglossary[title = Symbols and Acronyms]
    \clearpage
    \mainmatter

\chapter{C1}
Blah blah.
\section{C2S1}
Blah. And now for the tree:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=150pt}}
\Tree [.Clause_1 [.Subject_1:\\NP [.Adj Furious ] [.N listeners ] ] [.Predicate_1:\\VP [.Predicator\\V demanded ] [.Complement:\\Clause_2 [.Marker:\\Subordinator (NULL) ] [.Clause_2 [.Subject_2:\\NP [.N he ] ] [.Predicate_2:\\VP\\Predicator_2:\\V resign ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
Here we admire the tree's beauty.

    \backmatter
    % bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

    \printbibheading
    \printbibliography[keyword = written, heading = subbibliography, title = {Written Sources}]
    \printbibliography[keyword = corpus, heading = subbibliography, title = {Corpora Consulted}]
    \printbibliography[keyword = software, heading = subbibliography, title = {Software Used}]
\end{document}
```

The document does not compile, and there is a list of what look like syntax errors:

```
line 241: Missing \endcsname inserted. ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}
line 241: Missing \begin{document}. ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}
line 241: Extra \endcsname. ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}
line 241: Argument of \automath@two has an extra }. ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}
line 241: Paragraph ended before \automath@two was complete. ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}
line 241: Missing \endcsname inserted. ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}
line 241: Too many }'s. ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}
line 241: Extra \endcsname. ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}
line 241: Missing \begin{document}. ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}
line 1089: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. }
line 503: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined(Font) using `OT1/cmr/bx/n' instead
```

...and so on. EDIT: After posting the first version I noticed that the `tikz` package was accidentally being called twice in the preamble. This has now been fixed, and the error messages updated.

This is extremely frustrating, because `tikz-qtree` seems to have the functionality I want, i.e. unlike `qtree`, it allows the words of the parsed sentence to all be displayed at the same level.

Comment: Welcome! This is because of all the underscores. Use `\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=150pt}}
\Tree [.Clause\_1 [.Subject\_1:\\NP [.Adj Furious ] [.N listeners ] ] 
[.Predicate\_1:\\VP [.Predicator\\V demanded ] [.Complement:\\Clause\_2 
[.Marker:\\Subordinator (NULL) ] [.Clause\_2 [.Subject\_2:\\NP [.N he ] ] 
[.Predicate\_2:\\VP\\Predicator\_2:\\V resign ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: Hi, I replaced my code by yours with a verbatim copypaste, but am still getting a string of error messages beginning with ```Missing \endcsname inserted. ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your statement, it compiles on my updated TeXLive2020 installation. The main problem is that your document is far from minimal, the resulting tree too wide and so on. Those who write an answer will be quite busy with off-topic stuff.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat The problem had two layers. Fingers crossed, it seems that loading the `gb4e` package only after `tikz` and `tikz-qtree` has fixed the main problem. But you were right about the underscores. Their purpose was to introduce subscripts, and this worked fine with the `qtree` package where the original tree was created. But with `tikz-qtree` they caused a problem. This seems to have been fixed by using `\textsubscript{}` instead. However, the third problem of excessive tree width remains. Its cause is that `tikz-qtree` is ignoring my linebreaks (marked by \\\) in the node labels.

Comment: If you add `\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}`, say,  then the `\\ ` will no longer be ignored. That is, you need to specify some alignment, it can also be `left` etc. You probably need to change some distances. too.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you. This is now resolved. There were some remaining issues with graphical alignment, but they were easy enough to fix by looking at the [manual](https://www.texlive.info/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-qtree/tikz-qtree-manual.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, glad to hear!